# How to keep Panel overlay above fixed footer on Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have this code within my main file in Jquery mobile:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" data-position="left" class="ui-response" >
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search ..." data-inset="true" >
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-divider-theme="c">A</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
        ...
    </ul>

    <a data-role="button" data-rel="close">Close</a>

</div>
```

It basically serves to create a sliding panel.

My footer however is applied with fixed with "data-position="fixed". The div started with this:

So my Problem is how can you make the panel appear above the fixed footer?

I notice that the fixed footer was applied with this styling:

```
.ui-footer-fixed {
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

However, even if the panel above, was styled with z-index above 1000, it still does appear above the fixed footer.

Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your panel inside the content-div just under your regular content.